# Como mostrar datos de un array en concreto

Tags: javascript, array, api, objeto, fetch

estoy intentando mostrar los datos de un array pero muestro todos. Me gustaría mostrar los datos del array data[200...299]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy empleando fetch y lo muestro en el siguiente codigo.

```
datos.forEach(muestra => {
    const { id, title, thumbnailUrl  } = muestra;
    resultado.innerHTML += `
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 card m-2 p-2">
           
    <img src="${thumbnailUrl}" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="">
    <div class="col card-body">
    <p class="fs-5 "><a class="link" href="/juego-online.html?gid=${id}">${title}</a></p>
    
                `;

  });
```

Comment: Por favor trata de no usar imagenes a menos que sea necesario, la captura que usaste la puedes copiar del navegador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usar el metodo `slice` de los array.

```js
let datos = ['a','b','c','d','e']
let recorteDatos = datos.slice(2,5)
console.log({ recorteDatos })
```

En tu código sería algo así

```
    let recorteDatos = datos.slice(200,300)

    recorteDatos.forEach(muestra => {
        const { id, title, thumbnailUrl } = muestra;
        resultado.innerHTML += `
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 card m-2 p-2">
                    <img src="${thumbnailUrl}" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="">
                    <div class="col card-body">
                        <p class="fs-5 ">
                            <a class="link" href="/juego-online.html?gid=${id}">${title}</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alexander! funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Hola, dicen que mejor que dar gracías es puntuar la respuesta como valida. :)

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la lógica del `.forEach`, el segundo parámetro es el indice, entonces lo puedes evaluar en cada iteración:

```js
const resultado = document.getElementById("resutado")

const datos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

datos.forEach((muestra, i) => {

  if (i >= 3 && i <= 5) { // <-- El índice entre 3 y 5 inclusive

    resultado.innerHTML += `datos ${muestra} `;

  }


});
```

```html
<div id="resutado">

</div>
```